# Remove the button "demo mode" on prestashop 1.6

Tags: admin, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to erase the button on the homepage, but to delete (red) also clears other options other menus (green), I would like to know how to delete or hide the button (red) without affecting the other buttons (green ).

Any suggestions?

------> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRwkh.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can override the method `initPageHeaderToolbar()` of the controller `AdminDashboardController`.

Put this file under `/override/controllers/admin/AdminDashboardController.php`:

```
<?php

class AdminDashboardController extends AdminDashboardControllerCore {
    public function initPageHeaderToolbar()
    {
        parent::initPageHeaderToolbar();
        unset($this->page_header_toolbar_btn['switch_demo']);
    }
}
```

Then delete the file `/cache/class_index.php` and the button will disappear from your Dashboard.

Comment: I would like to hide the Help button, what is the name of the attribute ? thanks a lot in advance